# mitmproxy configuration to intercept HTTPS

Tags: proxy, mitmproxy

I'm using mitmproxy to intercept traffic, HTTP Traffic is being intercepted but HTTPS traffic is not being intercepted for some reason (?)

Using the default config with the command

```
mitmweb
Web server listening at http://127.0.0.1:8081/
Proxy server listening at http://*:8080
```

My proxy config:

[image]

Do I have to set a new config? Any help?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to intercept HTTPS traffic, you have to install certificate generated by MITM through http://mitm.it after you set your proxy.

After you visit http://mitm.it , download your certificate according to your Operating System. Then restart mitmproxy to check HTTPS traffic.

However, there are some traffic which is protected using [Certificate Pinning](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29988/what-is-certificate-pinning) , so mitmproxy cannot intercept. For example, the Twitter app, or Instagram App.

### reference

- https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/concepts-certificates/
- https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-ignoredomains/